# After Handle frame, control is not returning back to application robot Framework

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

After handling the pop up dialog using Handle Alert, the unselect frame step is not executing. Getting timeout error. I have increased timeout but it is still not working.

```
Navigate To Menu    Cycle Count Task Rules    Configuration
Select the option   ${CYCLECOUNT_TASK_SEARCH_CHECKBOX}  AA
select frame  ${WMS_Iframe}
click element  ${CYCLECOUNT_TASK_ACTION_RUN}
${alert_message}   Handle Alert     timeout=4s
log   ${alert_message}    console=${True}
sleep   5s
should be equal as strings  ${alert_message}  Request Submitted  msg=Failed to submit request for generating Cycle Count Task
unselect frame
```

TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000